# Practicing pointers, how do I get rid of this warning?

Tags: c, pointers

How do I get rid of this warning? I *think* it functions correctly but I'm not sure. I'm new to programming and want to practice more on pointers. I am coding a program that takes the current memory address of variableName[i] and prints it with the correct offset calculating the size of the string variableName contains.

```
cc     testing.c   -o testing
testing.c: In function ‘main’:
testing.c:10:6: warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from 
incompatible pointer type ‘char (*)[15]’ [-Wincompatible- 
pointer-types]
ptr = &variableName;
     ^
```

Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TESTING 15

int main()
{

    char variableName[TESTING] = "Hello World";
    int *ptr, stringSize, inc;
    ptr = &variableName;
    inc = *ptr;
    stringSize = sizeof(variableName);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        inc = inc + stringSize;
        printf("variableName[%d]: '%s'\t0x%x\n", i, variableName, inc);
    }
    printf("\nAddress to Pointer *ptr: 0x%x\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: define ptr as char *ptr

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the functioning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I think both pointer and variable whose address pointer is storing should be of same data type,in your case the pointer should be of char type;i.e- char *ptr

Comment: Thank you. I still get a similar warning message.

Comment: testing.c: In function ‘main’:
testing.c:11:6: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char (*)[15]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  ptr = &variableName;
      ^

Comment: your code has one for error,use "ptr=variableName" instead of " ptr = &variableName";

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here.

Your warning comes from the fact that you declared `ptr` to be a pointer to `int` (`int *`), but the expression `&variableName` has type “pointer to 15-element array of `char`”, or `char (*)[15]`.  If you want `ptr` to point to individual elements of the `variableName` array, then you want to declare it as a pointer to *`char`*:

```
char *ptr;
```

and you would set it to point to the first element of the array using either

```
ptr = &variableName[0];
```

*or*

```
ptr = variableName; // no & operator
```

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type “array of `T`” will be converted (“decay”) to an expression of “pointer to `T`”, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.

Note that the expressions `&variableName`, `variableName`, and `&variableName[0]` all yield the same *value* (the address of an array is the same as the address of its first element), but the *types* of the expressions are different (`char (*)[15]`, `char *`, and `char *`, respectively) and type matters, especially when doing pointer arithmetic.

Your code has other problems, but this should get you past the first hurdle.